# Browser Cache Issue

Tags: symfony, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

I have a Symfony2 app using assetic. Everything is fine except that in localhost my assetic assets does not get cached by browser.

Any idea why the following assets does not get served cached with response 304 and in milliseconds but instead with 200 response and takes about 15 seconds....

**Response Headers**

Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   max-age=604800
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    application/javascript
Date    Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:26:55 GMT
Etag    "159d57-511b83723ef71-gzip"
Expires Fri, 27 Mar 2015 13:26:55 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:23:00 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding

**Request Headers**

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  XDEBUG_SESSION=16069
Host    localhost
If-Modified-Since   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:23:00 GMT
If-None-Match   "159d57-511b83723ef71-gzip"
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0

---

Even if I go directly to this file through browser and then press F5 cache is not working.... But instead in other files i get 304 instead of 200...

Comment: Do you have `assetic_use_controller` set to `true` in your configuration for assetic? That would force symfony to serve the request instead of the filesystem.

Comment: i use assetic_use_controller: false

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for trouble, problem was the Apache deflate bug when using ETAGs. By disabling ETAGs its working fine and returns 304.